# How to add a custom block to an email template using a module

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create a custom block in the order confirmed email to add some information about a custom shipping method.

This is what I tried so far, but it doesn't show my block in the email.

In /app/code/moduleA/moduleB/view/frontend/layout folder I created **sales_order_info_links.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <block class="moduleA\moduleB\Block\moduleApickuppointemail" name="moduleApickuppointemail" before="items" template="moduleA_moduleB::moduleApickuppointemail.phtml" />
   </body>
</page>
```

In /app/code/moduleA/moduleB/Block folder I created **moduleApickuppointemail.php**

```
<?php
namespace moduleA\moduleB\Block;

class moduleApickuppointemail extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }

}
```

In /app/code/moduleA/moduleB/view/frontend/templates I created `moduleApickuppointemail.phtml`

```
<?php

/**
 * @var \moduleA\moduleB\Block\moduleApickuppointemail $block
 */

echo $block->sayHello();
```

But my code isn't working, nothing is shown in the email.

Can some please guide me on how to add custom blocks in the order confirmed email (shipping section if possible) using a module.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to override the order template or you can just add handle in the new order template.

Create file `vendor/modulename/etc/email_templates.xml`

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="sales_email_order_template" label="New Order" file="order_new.html" type="html" module="Vendor_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_order_guest_template" label="New Order for Guest" file="order_new_guest.html" type="html" module="Vendor_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Add handler in the email template file or you can edit email template from magento edit directly and add the below content in the email

`{{layout handle="sales_order_info_links" order=$order area="frontend"}}`

now create a layout handler `vendor/modulename/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_info_links.xml`

add below content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email information" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Email\Info" name="moduleApickuppointemail" template="email/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

create block file `Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Email/info.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Email;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Items\AbstractItems;

class Info extends AbstractItems
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

now create phtml file `Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/email/info.phtml`

add Below content

```php
<?php

// incase order data required
$order = $this->getOrder();

/**
 * @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Email\Info $block
 */
echo $block->sayHello();
```